# from colour.plotting import * fails after pip install colour

Tags: python, colors, pip

I installed colour package using pip as per instructions in https://pypi.org/project/colour/

The examples given in the link above also works fine

but after I do import colour and `colour.__version__` fails to print the version

Also there is a `from colour.plotting import *` also fails and returns an *ImportError: no module named colour.plotting. colour is not a package*.

Then how to correctly install it and get colour.plotting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install a different `colour` from https://pypi.org/project/colour-science/:

```
pip install colour-science
```

See the docs at https://www.colour-science.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped